# Node.js get Exec parameters/command in Callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, exec

I have multiple images I want to manipulate(imagemagick's convert command) in my filesystem. The number of images will be dynamic, but for this example lets use 8. None of these images are dependent on each other so I don't want to call 8 synchronous `exec`s (`execSync`).

Current code:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    outfile = 'finename123',
    jsonreturn = [],
    done = function(){
        //all images done move on.
    },
    i = 1;
for(; i <= 8; i++){
    var angle = (i - 1) * 45,
        bg = __dirname + '/../contentRam/pov/mug11-' + angle + '.png',
        child = exec('convert  ' + bg + ' ' + outfile + i + '.png -compose darken -resize 400x400 -composite png:-', {
            encoding: 'binary',
            maxBuffer: 5000 * 1024
        }, function(error, stdout, stderr){
            jsonreturn.push({
                src: 'data:image/png;base64,' + new Buffer(stdout, 'binary').toString('base64'),
                angle: angle
            });

            console.log(angle);

            if(jsonreturn.length === 8){
                done();
            }
        });
}
```

As you can see my basic problem is that `angle` will always be the last one (315 in this case) because it finished the `for` before any of the callbacks run. Is there any way for me to either pass a value along with the data `exec` is returning into the callback so I know which file just finished without making it synchronous? I've looked into being able to get the parameters or the whole command that was called with `exec` inside the callback, but I've had no luck. I've also looked into extra parameters for imagemagick's `convert` command to pass extra data, also with no luck.

The only other thing I can think of is making the for loop not run `exec` but rather write to a string. So everything from `child =` and on to the end of the `exec` would be a string. Once that is done each of the **string** `exec`'s will have the correct parameters **and** the right data in the callbacks, because at this point it is not relying on the `i` outside of the callback to see which `exec` it is on, the callback is literally written out the way it needs to execute. This means there will be(in this case) 8 different `exec` functions with callbacks and all in a string that would be `eval`ed. I can't do this manually because there is a dynamic number of images (sometimes 8, other times 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` or any other paraller method from [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library:

```
var async = require('async')
  , exec = require('child_process').exec
  , files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']

async.map(files
  , function (file, callback) {
    // you get the context of each file
    exec('exec some command with your file', {} , function(error, stdout, stderr){
      // you can use the same file reference
      callback(null, {
        src: '' // your buffer
      , angle: files.indexOf(file) * 20 // calculate angle based on the current file
      })
    })
  }
  , function (err, results) {
    // results have all {src,angle} items 
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library. Especially [async.waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) method. I think it's exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Correct me if I'm wrong but `async.waterfall` basically allows for passing data from 1 async function to the next and so on. This basically makes each async function not run at the same time but in order(this is the opposite of what I want to do). My problem isn't the passing of data from one async function to another. My problem is that inside each of the callbacks themselves I have no idea which of the `exec` commands this callback belongs to, so I don't know what file finished(because even though they start in order they *can* complete out of order).

Comment: You're right about `async.waterfall`.

Well, you can try to use `async.parallel` then for your requirements. Hope it helps.